# Getting logout after refresh of page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have asp.net application which communicates with API.

I have a problem with authentication - everything works fine. I get logged in, but when I refresh the page I get logged out.

I am not completely sure with this code for loggin. Do you have any idea how to do it better? I need to authorize against the REST API.

**this is my login form:**

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("LogInUser", "api/User", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", OnComplete = "OnLogInCompleted", LoadingElementId = "loadingImage" }))
{
    <fieldset class="login-form-box">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="login-label-box">@Html.Label("Username")</td>
                <td class="login-label-box">@Html.Label("Password")</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >@Html.TextBox("username", null, new {@class = "login-inout"})</td>
                <td>@Html.Password("password", null, new {@class = "login-inout"})</td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="LogIn" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>@Ajax.ActionLink("Register", "MainBodyContentPartial",
                                new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "contentBox", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
                                                    HttpMethod = "GET", OnComplete = "OnContentChanged" })</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**here is APIController which is called by this Ajax.Form:**

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("LogInUser")]
    [System.Web.Mvc.RequireHttps]
    public User LogInUser(string username, string password)
    {
        if(username == null || password == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        string hashedPassword = GetHashString(password);
        var selectedUser = DatabaseService.Inst.GetUserByUsernameAndPassword(username, hashedPassword);
        if(selectedUser == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
        if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(selectedUser.Role))
        {
            var userRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(selectedUser.Username);
            if (userRoles != null && userRoles.Any())
            {
                Roles.RemoveUserFromRoles(selectedUser.Username, userRoles);
            }
            Roles.AddUserToRole(selectedUser.Username, selectedUser.Role);
        }

        selectedUser.Password = "";
        return selectedUser;
    }
```

**and here is javascript code called when authorization is completed:**

```
function OnLogInCompleted(result) {
displayWaiting();
var loggedUser = result.responseJSON;
if (!loggedUser) {
    DisplayStatusMessage("Login failed.");
    return;
}
DisplayStatusMessage("You are logged in as " + loggedUser.Username);

$('#MainLoginFormBox').load(url + '/Content/LoggedUserContentPartial');
$('#navigationMenu').load(url + '/Content/UserMenuContentPartial');
$('#contentBox').load(url + '/Content/UserHomeContentPartial');
OnContentChanged();
hideWaiting();
return;
```

}

Comment: What happens if you log in and hit those pages manually? I'm assuming they're local to your app. I've had issues with javascript pages/remote loading not passing or keeping cookies. If it works when you hit it manually, I'd be willing to bet that's the issue.

Comment: I am using ajax with only partial view, so I can't try that (or I don't know how to do it :D )

Comment: you can't login and then go to whatever `url + '/Content/LoggedUserContentPartial'` is in your browser?

Comment: oh I can load partialView, but all my page in loaded via Ajax.

Comment: I understand that, but what we're after is to eliminate ajax as the cause of your issue. So can you load it a different way just to test it out?

Comment: I can load it - for example, user info page, and after refresh, user is still logged in

Comment: Just a dumb question: do you set a session or cookie, do you need a session or cookie?

Comment: I have probably dumb answer :D I thought I am setting it with this (not sure about that, I am new to ASP.Net) FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);